# Which primes satisfy this modular property?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, tetration

Let $x$ be a residue$\mod p$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Im searching for such $p$ such that there exists a function $f(x)$ with propery

$f(f(x)) - 2^x \equiv 0 \mod p $

for all values of $x$.

I got this question from here :

http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=940

Comment: Thanks for the edit @abiessu.